# Firefox rendering two overlaid images with slight height differences

Tags: css, firefox

I'm building a header for my website. On the left side is a logo which has an underline at the bottom of the image. I then use another image underlaid to continue this underline to the right side of the screen. You can see at http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/.

The problem is that in Firefox the heights of the underlines in the two images are often slightly different. The two images are the exact same height, both pngs, both outputted from the same photoshop file. In Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari the underlines are always the exact same height. Below is an image with the artifact taking place. 
[image: Firefox overlaid image with slight height change]

These are the two images.

[image: phoenix header underline]

and

[image: phoenix logo]

When changing the browser window size in Firefox, this effect will appear and disappear.

I've played with several aspects of css including `height`, `max-height`, `position`, `vertical-align`. I've also tried taking the logo out of it's containing `<a>` tag to no avail. The same thing happens when the non-logo image exists as a background of the parent element rather than an `<img>`.

Header HTML code:

```
<div class="top-info">
             *top search bar code removed for brevity*          
</div>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <img src="http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/wp-content/themes/boston-child/images/phoenix-header-border.png" style="">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au">
        <img src="http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/wp-content/themes/boston-child/images/phoenix-logo.png" alt="PhoenixWeb">
    </a>    
</div>
<div class="triangle visible-md visible-lg">
</div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
    <img src="http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/wp-content/themes/boston-child/images/phoenix-header-border.png" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:80px;">
    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li class="menu-portfolio"><a href="http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/portfolio-4-columns/">Portfolio</a></li>
        *nav items removed for brevity*
</ul>    
</div>
```

CSS is a bit complicated as this is WordPress and I am using a child theme. I can add this in later if noone has an answer without seeing it summarised here. If anyone can cast some illumination on the problem it would be much appreciated!

Comment: why not combine the two images into a single image? if you need the orange bar to continue on the right just use css or another image.

Comment: @Timmerz The logo is nested in an anchor link. I suppose I could do a whole lot of absolute positioning to get one wide image and an anchor link positioned where they need to be. Also, my first attempt to get this to work was to have the orange bar as an element border - if that's what you mean by css. The height difference was the same with that solution.

Comment: I think you can go about this in a better way. what is the point of overlaying two images in the browser vs combining them in a photo editor? the result would be the same to a user, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what was causing the slight height changes was the fact that I was stretching the 'underline' image across the width of the header. It seems that in Firefox compressing or stretching an image horizontally has an effect on the way it is rendered in the vertical direction.

By replacing the underline image with an images as wide as the screen and doing no stretching, the two images lined up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the problem on my Firefox but you can try not to put line breaks after your `<img />` tags as I know it sometimes adds unwanted and unexpected gaps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a mixture of both your css and those two images.

Upon inspecting your site at the URL provided, it appears that you are scaling down the images to be 80px tall. The original height of these images is 295px and 295/80 is 3.6875. This causes the browser to have to calculate uneven pixels, which is where the problem is coming from. Ideally your assets should be the same height as what you are trying to show them at unless trying to accommodate retina devices.

I would suggest resizing the actual images in photoshop to be exactly 80px tall.

Comment: I just tried resizing both images to a multiple of 3 pixels (both directions) and then tried setting both images to 80px high. There is some improvement at 80px. But a difference in height is still there sadly.